# Decompose Polynomials

Tags: code-golf, math, number, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given an integral polynomial of degree strictly greater than one, completely decompose it into a composition of integral polynomials of degree strictly greater than one.

#### Details

- An *integral polynomial* is a polynomial with only integers as coefficients.
- Given two polynomials `p` and `q` the *composition* is defined by `(p∘q)(x):=p(q(x))`.
- The [*decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_decomposition) of an integral polynomial `p` is a finite ordered sequence of integral polynomials `q1,q2,...,qn` where `deg qi > 1` for all `1 ≤ i ≤ n` and `p(x) = q1(q2(...qn(x)...))`, and all `qi` are not further decomposable. The decomposition is not necessarily unique.
- You can use e.g. lists of coefficients or built in polynomial types as input and output.
- Note that many builtins for this task actually decompose the polynomials over a given *field* and not necessarily integers, while this challenge requires a decomposition integer polynomials. (Some integer polynomials might  admit decomposition into integer polynomials as well as decomposition that contain rational polynomials.)

#### Examples

```
x^2 + 1
[x^2 + 1] (all polynomials of degree 2 or less are not decomposable)
x^6 - 6x^5 + 15x^4 - 20x^3 + 15x^2 - 6 x - 1
[x^3 - 2, x^2 - 2x + 1]
x^4 - 8x^3 + 18x^2 - 8x + 2 
[x^2 + 1, x^2 - 4x + 1]
x^6 + x^2 + 1
[x^3 + x + 1, x^2]
x^6
[x^2, x^3]
x^8 + 4x^6 + 6x^4 + 4x^2 + 4 = (x^2 + 1)^4 + 3
[x^2 + 3, x^2, x^2 + 1]
x^6 + 6x^4 + x^3 + 9x^2 + 3x - 5
[x^2 + x - 5, x^3 + 3*x], [x^2 + 5*x + 1, x^3 + 3*x - 2]
```

Use Maxima for generating examples: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y02syMxN/P@/QKNCU8HKVqEizljbSKtC29iaqxAuZKRboW1ozVUEFzBV0AaSJgq6IEltM2uugqLMvBKNgvycypTU5PzcAg0TrUKNIg2QqZqaOkDC@v9/AA)

Some decomposition algorithms can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717185800122) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717189800276).

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 84 bytes

```
f(p)=[if(q'',[f(q),r],p)|r<-x*divisors(p\x),r''&&p==subst(q=substpol(p,r,x),x,r)][1]
```

Based on the algorithm described [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717185800122).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3dCoMwDIVfJXihrbYwf3Ew9yJOwTE2CjJjdaODvbtLrcJucnLyJTnYaSUfuCx3hryq1Z2NQSBqEi50I5B/9Uma8Kbeahr0xPBiCASB72NVTa/rNLPRKQ49Q6EFcSM0b@q4WTrE/sMQ5BlQq@dMrWeNBzaOC6hNm0AEsQDTFiChCE2b20FOTUaD5EBNuk8St0J1vbAL5c7LjZOSTdzHCP4DbCnJZaFjxRrivN3K9qMduNfHDadrct7w5Qc)

Comment: Do you check (or filter out) whether you actually get a decomposition into integral polynomials? (I'm asking because the algorithms in the linked paper describe the factorization over some field, and I don't know any Pari/GP.)

Comment: @flawr I'm using the second algorithm in the paper, which always returns integral polynomials when the input is integral. In fact, the `divisors` function in Pari/GP always returns [primitive polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_part_and_content) when it takes an integral polynomial. It can be proved that if `p=q∘r`, where `p` and `r` are integral, and `r` is primitive with `r(0)=0`, then `q` must also be integral. Here `p`, `q`, `r` correspond to `f`, `g`, `h` in the paper.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Decompose[#/.x->x+a,x]/.a->0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY47C4MwFIX3/ooLgkuj9jE4FKWDFboV6RYyRHu1gjGShJJS@tvTOJQ@psv5OOfcI7i5ouCmb7hrM1dgI8UkNdIgiW2U2yUnliUxj/JV6BQfLzXXOMnhriGDM68HpKWSoui73mhaeYMUx9Fgh4o@opRA@iSwZQQsm@9uMXfMeR8/2MmLfSmHCw02kMRgIcohWEPo/QQqvKHyU37eMt9xUv1o/vAXnMFbtx/C3As)

I have the example set up here to compose a random polynomial from random quadratics (or less), expand it out, and then try to decompose it.

It's necessary to complicate the polynomial with dummy variable (a) since the built-in will not attempt to decompose a monomial.

I notice that the answer often has much larger coefficients than in the original composition, but they are indeed always integers.

Comment: Where did you find the information that `Decompose[]` will always return integral polynomials (if fed with integer polynomials)? When discussing in chat recently we could not find anything about that.

Comment: Do `Options@Decompose` and it will tell you `{Modulus->0}`.  Now look up Modulus and you'll see "The setting Modulus->0 specifies the full ring \[DoubleStruckCapitalZ] of integers. "

Comment: Ah that is nice, thanks for elaborating!